# Xaml FlowDocument table - how to get the header on each page on a multi-page table?

Tags: xaml, flowdocument, xps

I've got a XAML FlowDocument containing a table with a lot of rows, spanning multiple pages, and I'm converting this FlowDocument to XPS.

Now I'm looking for a way to repeat the header of the table on each page.

I see two possible approaches:

1. Get the table to automagically print the header on each page.
2. Somehow by program find out how many rows the page can hold, stop the table there, start a new table with same content and header on the next page.

So far I got no luck for both approaches. Maybe someone has got an idea how to page-break a FlowDocument table?